# How should I train a SVM using julia?

Tags: machine-learning, julia, svm

Does anyone have experience of training a support vector machine (SVM) in Julia (1.4.1) ?

I tried the LIBSVM interface, but the example on the gituhub page gave an error :

````
# Load Fisher's classic iris data
iris = dataset("datasets", "iris")
# LIBSVM handles multi-class data automatically using a one-against-one strategy
labels = convert(Vector, iris[:Species])
# First dimension of input data is features; second is instances
instances = convert(Array, iris[:, 1:4])'
# Train SVM on half of the data using default parameters. See documentation
# of svmtrain for options
model = svmtrain(instances[:, 1:2:end], labels[1:2:end]);```

ERROR: MethodError: no method matching LIBSVM.SupportVectors(::Int32, ::Array{Int32,1}, ::CategoricalArray{String,1,UInt8,String,CategoricalValue{String,UInt8},Union{}}, ::Array{Float64,2}, ::Array{Int32,1}, ::Array{LIBSVM.SVMNode,1})
Closest candidates are:
LIBSVM.SupportVectors(::Int32, ::Array{Int32,1}, ::Array{T,1}, ::AbstractArray{U,2}, ::Array{Int32,1}, ::Array{LIBSVM.SVMNode,1}) where {T, U} at /home/benny/.julia/packages/LIBSVM/5Z99T/src/LIBSVM.jl:18
LIBSVM.SupportVectors(::LIBSVM.SVMModel, ::Any, ::Any) at /home/benny/.julia/packages/LIBSVM/5Z99T/src/LIBSVM.jl:27
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like `LIBSVM.jl` documentation is rather outdated and package was not updated appropriately, so it worth an issue (or at least pull request to update README).

Error that you see is not related to the package itself, but the fact that in current versions of `DataFrames.jl` and `RDatasets.jl` `labels` column is no longer `Vector` (as it was at the time when `LIBSVM.jl` was developed) but CategoricalArray. You can avoid this problem by converting CategoricalArray to usual `Vector{String}`. Complete example looks like this

```
using RDatasets, LIBSVM
using StatsBase, Printf # `mean` and `printf` are no longer in Base, and should be used explicitly

# Load Fisher's classic iris data
iris = dataset("datasets", "iris")

# LIBSVM handles multi-class data automatically using a one-against-one strategy
labels = string.(convert(Vector, iris[:Species]))

# First dimension of input data is features; second is instances
instances = convert(Array, iris[:, 1:4])'

# Train SVM on half of the data using default parameters. See documentation
# of svmtrain for options
model = svmtrain(instances[:, 1:2:end], labels[1:2:end]);

# Test model on the other half of the data.
(predicted_labels, decision_values) = svmpredict(model, instances[:, 2:2:end]);

# Compute accuracy
@printf "Accuracy: %.2f%%\n" mean((predicted_labels .== labels[2:2:end]))*100
```

Alternatively, you can use [MLJ.jl](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/MLJ.jl) or [ScikitLearn.jl](https://github.com/cstjean/ScikitLearn.jl)
which should correctly wrap LIBSVM.jl on their own.

Answer (score 3):

Oskin's answer is for an older version.

In the current version, it should be modified as,

```
using RDatasets, LIBSVM
using StatsBase, Printf # `mean` and `printf` are no longer in Base, and should be used explicitly

# Load Fisher's classic iris data
iris = dataset("datasets", "iris")

# LIBSVM handles multi-class data automatically using a one-against-one strategy
labels = string.(convert(Vector, iris[:,:Species]))

# First dimension of input data is features; second is instances
instances = Matrix(iris[:, 1:4])'

# Train SVM on half of the data using default parameters. See documentation
# of svmtrain for options
model = svmtrain(instances[:, 1:2:end], labels[1:2:end]);

# Test model on the other half of the data.
(predicted_labels, decision_values) = svmpredict(model, instances[:, 2:2:end]);

# Compute accuracy
@printf "Accuracy: %.2f%%\n" mean((predicted_labels .== labels[2:2:end]))*100
```

Comment: This is great improvement and should be accepted answer.